# Выполнять цикл с интервалов по времени

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Хочу сделать чтоб цикл в методе `someTask()` выполнялся с интервалов в 10 минут. У меня цикл выполняется всегда. И как только выполнился, начинает тут же заново.
Буду очень благодарен за вашу помощь.

Код метода `someTask()`

```
void someTask() {
      new Thread(new Runnable() {

              public void run() {

              while (parseRep < 2) {
              Document doc = null;
               try {
                   Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("http://mobayle.ru/aut.php")
                            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                            .execute();
                   response = Jsoup.connect("http://mobayle.ru/login.php")
                           .header("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8")
                           .data("nick", loginAuth
                                ,"pass", passAuth)
                           .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                           .timeout(30000).execute();


                    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://mobayle.ru").cookies(response.cookies()).get();
                    Element blockRega = doc.select("div.foot").first();
                    nav2Reg = blockRega.text();


                    Elements kollMess = doc.select("a[href*=new_mess] div.nav2 font[color=red]");
                    kollNewMess = kollMess.text();

                    System.out.println(kollNewMess);
                    System.out.println(nav2Reg);

                    if (kollNewMess.equals(kkkmmSs)) {
                    }else{
                        sendNotif();
                        System.out.println(kollNewMess);
                    }


                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


              } //while


              }
        }).start();


  }
```

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, этот вопрос задается регулярно в цикле с интервалом по времени.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow не понял вас

Comment: Сегодня подобный вопрос уже был, если я не ошибаюсь.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow А, вы об этом. Дело в том что в том вопросе я сразу предоставил не полный код метода. И ответ который я там получил у меня не как не удается прикрепить к этому методу

Answer (score 2):

```
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
    // код внутри выполняется в отдельном потоке и запускается каждые 10 минут
}, 0, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать класс [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

```
final TimerTask task = () -> someTask();
Timer.schedule(task, 0, 10*1000*60 /*repeat every 10 min*/);
```